# How can I use php loop inside if else statement

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

```
if (isset($_GET['language']) && !empty($_GET['language'] && $_SESSION['language'] !== $_GET['language'])) {
    if ($_GET['language'] === 'en') {
      $_SESSION['language'] = 'en';
    } elseif ($_GET['language'] === 'ar') {
      $_SESSION['language'] = 'ar';
    } elseif ($_GET['language'] === 'de') {
      $_SESSION['language'] = 'de';
    } else {
      $_SESSION['language'] = $default_language;
    }
  }
```

I would like to loop only elseif statements. Is there away to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you could just set `$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['language']` if `$_GET['language']` is set. No need for lots of `if`s. If you want to make sure `$_GET['language']` can only take certain values use [in_​array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Agreed, your example is a big pile of redundant hard-coding

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `isset` and `empty` as `empty` will do that for you.

This also checks if the language is in one of the specific ones (using `in_array`) and if it isn't then it uses the default...

```
if (!empty($_GET['language']) && $_SESSION['language'] !== $_GET['language']) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = in_array($_GET['language'], ['en', 'ar', 'de'])
            ? $_GET['language'] : $default_language;
}
```

Comment: Need to close the `empty` sooner. `!empty($_GET['language'])`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a loop here. If your intention is to whitelist the available languages then put a list in an array and use `in_array()`:

```
$languages = ['ar','de','en'];
if (isset($_GET['language']) && in_array($_GET['language'], $languages)) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['language'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $default_language;
}
```